# How to install torch properly?

Tags: python, torch

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I a trying to install torch at my computer:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

**I do not have CUDA. 
I am using Anaconda, as you see.
Python in version 3.6.
Pycharm is my IDE.**

I receive this:

```
Collecting package metadata: failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: librosa/librosa
  channel url: https://github.com/librosa/librosa
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

, so I am trying this:

`conda config --show-sources`
and as an output I have this:

```
channels:
  - https://github.com/librosa/librosa
  - defaults
```

Next step I took was trying to install LIBROSA with:

```
easy_install librosa

Searching for librosa
Best match: librosa 0.6.3
Removing librosa 0.6.2 from easy-install.pth file
Adding librosa 0.6.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/marta/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for librosa
Finished processing dependencies for librosa
```

But still, I receive the same failure with torch installation.
What might be wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `librosa` channel (why would you need it anyway, it's channel is `conda-forge`, see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/librosa)). Issue this command: `conda config --remove channels https://github.com/librosa/librosa`.

You should be able to install pytorch using `conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch` as you tried previously.

For `librosa` it would be `conda install -c conda-forge librosa`, don't use `easy_install` for package installation (even when creating your own use `setuptools` instead).